# Not created client object of laravel unit testing

Tags: php, laravel

I have laravel TestCase class

```
<?php

class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
     */
    public function setUp(){
        return true;
    }

    public function createApplication()
    {
        $unitTesting = true;

        $testEnvironment = 'testing';

        return require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
    }

}
```

I'm extending this class into ExampleTest as follows

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {

        $inputs = array('username' => '', 'password' => '');
        $this->client->request('POST', '/app/1.0/auth/testLogin', $inputs);

        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

While run this test

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function request() on a non-object in /opt/Work/tapes/backend/api/app/tests/ExampleTest.php on line 14**

error occured.

I go through debug and came to know **client object is not created**.

I tried my best, but not able to solve this problem.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem, I solved it by changing TestCase class file as follows -

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Testing;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

abstract class TestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * The Illuminate application instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    protected $app;

    /**
     * The HttpKernel client instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Client
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * Setup the test environment.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        if ( ! $this->app)
        {
            $this->refreshApplication();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Refresh the application instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function refreshApplication()
    {
        $this->app = $this->createApplication();

        $this->client = $this->createClient();

        $this->app->setRequestForConsoleEnvironment();

        $this->app->boot();
    }

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * Needs to be implemented by subclasses.
     *
     * @return Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
     */
    abstract public function createApplication();

    /**
     * Call the given URI and return the Response.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  string  $uri
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @param  array   $files
     * @param  array   $server
     * @param  string  $content
     * @param  bool    $changeHistory
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function call()
    {
        call_user_func_array(array($this->client, 'request'), func_get_args());

        return $this->client->getResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Call the given HTTPS URI and return the Response.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  string  $uri
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @param  array   $files
     * @param  array   $server
     * @param  string  $content
     * @param  bool    $changeHistory
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function callSecure()
    {
        $parameters = func_get_args();

        $parameters[1] = 'https://localhost/'.ltrim($parameters[1], '/');

        return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'call'), $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Call a controller action and return the Response.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  string  $action
     * @param  array   $wildcards
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @param  array   $files
     * @param  array   $server
     * @param  string  $content
     * @param  bool    $changeHistory
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function action($method, $action, $wildcards = array(), $parameters = array(), $files = array(), $server = array(), $content = null, $changeHistory = true)
    {
        $uri = $this->app['url']->action($action, $wildcards, true);

        return $this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $files, $server, $content, $changeHistory);
    }

    /**
     * Call a named route and return the Response.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  array   $routeParameters
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @param  array   $files
     * @param  array   $server
     * @param  string  $content
     * @param  bool    $changeHistory
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function route($method, $name, $routeParameters = array(), $parameters = array(), $files = array(), $server = array(), $content = null, $changeHistory = true)
    {
        $uri = $this->app['url']->route($name, $routeParameters);

        return $this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $files, $server, $content, $changeHistory);
    }

    /**
     * Assert that the client response has an OK status code.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertResponseOk()
    {
        $response = $this->client->getResponse();

        $actual = $response->getStatusCode();

        /** @noinspection PhpInconsistentReturnPointsInspection */
        return $this->assertTrue($response->isOk(), 'Expected status code 200, got ' .$actual);
    }

    /**
     * Assert that the client response has a given code.
     *
     * @param  int  $code
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertResponseStatus($code)
    {
        /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection */
        /** @noinspection PhpInconsistentReturnPointsInspection */
        return $this->assertEquals($code, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }

    /**
     * Assert that the response view has a given piece of bound data.
     *
     * @param  string|array  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertViewHas($key, $value = null)
    {
        if (is_array($key)) /** @noinspection PhpInconsistentReturnPointsInspection */
            return $this->assertViewHasAll($key);

        /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedFieldInspection */
        $response = $this->client->getResponse()->original;

        if ( ! $response instanceof View)
        {
            /** @noinspection PhpInconsistentReturnPointsInspection */
            return $this->assertTrue(false, 'The response was not a view.');
        }

        if (is_null($value))
        {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $response->getData());
        }
        else
        {
            $this->assertEquals($value, $response->$key);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assert that the view has a given list of bound data.
     *
     * @param  array  $bindings
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertViewHasAll(array $bindings)
    {
        foreach ($bindings as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_int($key))
            {
                $this->assertViewHas($value);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->assertViewHas($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assert whether the client was redirected to a given URI.
     *
     * @param  string  $uri
     * @param  array   $with
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertRedirectedTo($uri, $with = array())
    {
        $response = $this->client->getResponse();

        $this->assertInstanceOf('Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse', $response);

        $this->assertEquals($this->app['url']->to($uri), $response->headers->get('Location'));

        $this->assertSessionHasAll($with);
    }

    /**
     * Assert whether the client was redirected to a given route.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @param  array   $with
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertRedirectedToRoute($name, $parameters = array(), $with = array())
    {
        $this->assertRedirectedTo($this->app['url']->route($name, $parameters), $with);
    }

    /**
     * Assert whether the client was redirected to a given action.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @param  array   $with
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertRedirectedToAction($name, $parameters = array(), $with = array())
    {
        $this->assertRedirectedTo($this->app['url']->action($name, $parameters), $with);
    }

    /**
     * Assert that the session has a given list of values.
     *
     * @param  string|array  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertSessionHas($key, $value = null)
    {
        if (is_array($key)) /** @noinspection PhpInconsistentReturnPointsInspection */
            return $this->assertSessionHasAll($key);

        if (is_null($value))
        {
            $this->assertTrue($this->app['session.store']->has($key), "Session missing key: $key");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->assertEquals($value, $this->app['session.store']->get($key));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assert that the session has a given list of values.
     *
     * @param  array  $bindings
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertSessionHasAll(array $bindings)
    {
        foreach ($bindings as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_int($key))
            {
                $this->assertSessionHas($value);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->assertSessionHas($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assert that the session has errors bound.
     *
     * @param  string|array  $bindings
     * @param  mixed  $format
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertSessionHasErrors($bindings = array(), $format = null)
    {
        $this->assertSessionHas('errors');

        $bindings = (array)$bindings;

        $errors = $this->app['session.store']->get('errors');

        foreach ($bindings as $key => $value)
        {
            if (is_int($key))
            {
                /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection */
                $this->assertTrue($errors->has($value), "Session missing error: $value");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->assertContains($value, $errors->get($key, $format));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assert that the session has old input.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function assertHasOldInput()
    {
        $this->assertSessionHas('_old_input');
    }

    /**
     * Set the currently logged in user for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface  $user
     * @param  string  $driver
     * @return void
     */
    public function be(UserInterface $user, $driver = null)
    {
        $this->app['auth']->driver($driver)->setUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * Seed a given database connection.
     *
     * @param  string  $class
     * @return void
     */
    public function seed($class = 'DatabaseSeeder')
    {
        $this->app['artisan']->call('db:seed', array('--class' => $class));
    }

    /**
     * Create a new HttpKernel client instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $server
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client
     */
    protected function createClient(array $server = array())
    {
        return new Client($this->app, $server);
    }

}
```